# Qt MainWindow Dark theme

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, themes

I'm learning Qt and do you know to set black theme for mainwindow at Qt? I think that it's doing by css stylesheet or anything like this. I hope at your help. Sorry for bad English!

Comment: I use this https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256772/dark-theme-for-qt-widgets

Answer (score 1):

You can do it:

```
QApplication::setStyle(const QString & style);
```

You may do it on qss stylesheet (it's like css)
For create your style file read more on Qt docs:
http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change it from its stylesheet.

```
QMainWindow{
     background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) 
}
```

Just add this styling in your stylesheet, and it will work.

Comment: But what is about a bar where close and hide buttons? The weren't changed to black