# change theme with radio button Qwidget in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, themes, qwidget, qradiobutton

I want to change my application Theme with `QRadioButton` in the `QWidget` application.
can anyone help me?
I have a Setting class that has some settings and one of them is changing the theme between dark and light.
it is a C++ app with OpenGL.

```
void Settings::on_DarkTheme_clicked()
{
    
}

void Settings::on_lightTheme_clicked()
{
    
}
```

what should I have to write in these 2 methods?

> I used .qss file like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


QSurfaceFormat fmt;
fmt.setVersion(3,3);
fmt.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
fmt.setSamples(8);
fmt.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::StereoBuffers);
fmt.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(fmt);

loadSettings();

App app(argc, argv);

QFile stylesheetFile("./Combinear.qss");
stylesheetFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString stylesheet = QLatin1String(stylesheetFile.readAll());
app.setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
MainWindow w;
w.show();
const auto returnValue = app.exec();
App::setFinished();
return returnValue;
}
```

but it didn't Work and I'm confused

Comment: FYI: [Qt MainWindow Dark theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692124/7478597), [Dark theme for Qt widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48256803/7478597)

Comment: these are static theme.
I want to change it from app dynamicly

Comment: The 2nd link (the one with Python) mentions "Dynamic Stylesheet Toggling". As far as I have seen, it boils down to call [QApplication::setStyleSheet()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop) with the style sheets loaded from file. (I'm sure it could be a resource as well.)

Comment: unforyunetly my app is c++ not py

Comment: unforyunetly my app is c++ not py

Comment: PyQt is just a language binding of Qt for Python. The underlying library is the same C++ library you are using. The classes and functions in Python have (in most cases) the exact same names as in C++. Sorry, that I googled it for you...

Comment: use 2 `.qss` file  and when you click in each theme change it

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I used .qss file my main method is below bot it didn't change

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I add a `radioButton` in my `mainwindow.ui` .

this is my `mainwindow.h` :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H

#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void  changedDark();

    void  changedLight();

private slots:
    void  on_radioButton_clicked(bool checked);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

and my `mainwindow.cpp` :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void  MainWindow::on_radioButton_clicked(bool checked)
{
    if (checked)
    {
        ui->radioButton->setText("Dark");
        emit  changedDark();
    }
    else
    {
        ui->radioButton->setText("Light");
        emit  changedLight();
    }
}
```

**and my main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow    w;

    w.show();

    QObject::connect(&w, &MainWindow::changedDark, &a, [&]
    {
        /**
         * Load the application style
         */
        QFile dark_styleFile(":/theme/themes/MaterialDark.qss");

        dark_styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

        /**
         * Apply the loaded stylesheet
         */
        QString style(dark_styleFile.readAll());
        a.setStyleSheet(style);
    });

    QObject::connect(&w, &MainWindow::changedLight, &a, [&]
    {
        /**
         * Load the application style
         */
        QFile light_styleFile(":/theme/themes/Ubuntu.qss");

        light_styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

        /**
         * Apply the loaded stylesheet
         */
        QString style(light_styleFile.readAll());
        a.setStyleSheet(style);
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

**This is my result:**

[image]

you can clone it from this repo:

https://github.com/parisa-hr/qt-theme-example