# Right justify QKeySequence in PyQt QAction Menu

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmenu, qkeysequence

How I can right justify the QKeySequence in PyQt5?

```
copy_absolute_path_action = (
    create_action(self, _("Copy Absolute Path"), QKeySequence(
        get_shortcut('explorer', 'copy absolute path')),
                  triggered=self.copy_absolute_path))
copy_relative_path_action = (
    create_action(self, _("Copy Relative Path"), QKeySequence(
        get_shortcut('explorer', 'copy relative path')),
                  triggered=self.copy_relative_path))
copy_file_clipboard_action = (
    create_action(self, _("Copy File to Clipboard"),
                  QKeySequence(get_shortcut('explorer', 'copy file')),
                  icon=ima.icon('editcopy'),
                  triggered=self.copy_file_clipboard))
save_file_clipboard_action = (
    create_action(self, _("Paste File from Clipboard"),
                  QKeySequence(get_shortcut('explorer', 'paste file')),
                  icon=ima.icon('editpaste'),
                  triggered=self.save_file_clipboard))
```

[image]

I want the key shortcuts to be right justified and the rest unchanged.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not use the pyqt4 tag since there is no complete compatibility between PyQt4 and PyQt5 (I suspect that there is no solution for PyQt4 but maybe for PyQt5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the solution is to implement a QProxyStyle:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MenuProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
        shortcut = ""
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_MenuItem:
            vals = option.text.split("\t")
            if len(vals) == 2:
                text, shortcut = vals
                option.text = text
        super(MenuProxyStyle, self).drawControl(element, option, painter, widget)
        if shortcut:
            margin = 10 # QStyleHelper::dpiScaled(5)
            self.proxy().drawItemText(painter, option.rect.adjusted(margin, 0, -margin, 0), 
                QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter,
                option.palette, option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled, 
                shortcut, QtGui.QPalette.Text)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu("File", self)
        self._proxy = MenuProxyStyle(menu.style())
        menu.setStyle(self._proxy)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(menu)

        # create icons
        data = [("Copy Absolute Path", "Ctrl+Alt+C"),
                 ("Copy Relative Path", "Ctrl+Shift+C"),
                 ("Copy File to Clipboard", "Ctrl+C")]

        for text, shortcut in data:
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(self, 
                text=text, 
                shortcut=QtGui.QKeySequence(shortcut))
            menu.addAction(action)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, Genius, Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can this be applied to a context menus?? I could not make it work on context menus!!

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti I see that in the case of contexts menus shorcuts are not shown

Comment: Thanks again, your suggestion works perfect. Do you know How I can preserve the original appearance. The suggested method changes the color of the menus

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti try changing `self._proxy = MenuProxyStyle(menu.style())` to `self._proxy = MenuProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QApplication.style())`, if it does not work then you must provide a **[mcve]** to analyze where the problem is, in my case I do not observe the problem

Comment: Actually it is working perfect as you suggested with your original answer. It only does not work with dark theme. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48256803/6814154. Thanks again for your support.