# How do you enable macOS Dark Mode in PyQt5 (5.13)

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

I am making my first GUI application with PyQt5 but it does not currently work with dark mode.

**How do you enable dark mode in PyQt5?**

I user PyQt5 v5.13.0 and freeze the app with PyInstaller on Mac, Linux and Windows.

If you need more information or some of the code, please tell me.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I am also using PyQt5 v5.13 (I'm on v5.13.2) with Python 3.7.5 and dark mode is working out-of-the-box on macOS. I have not been able to get it to work on Windows and haven't tried Linux.

Answer (score 3):

#### Workaround for macOS X:

1. Compile your app
2. Add this into your apps's `Info.plist` (Found at `{APPNAME}/Contents/Info.plist`):

   ```xml
   <key>NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance</key>
   <string>False</string>
   ```

This can be automated by [running PyInstaller from python script](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#running-pyinstaller-from-python-code) and then editing `Info.plist` using `open()`.

Comment: Hi, can this be done before compiling the app i.e. while development? If yes, can you please explain how? Thanks!

Comment: No you can't (unless you are on os below 10.14). I just tested my app on light mode, then compiled and tested with dark mode.

Comment: Bless you.  This worked for me with PyQt5 `5.15.2` and Python `3.8.2`.  In fact, all I had to do to get this tip to work was amend the `info.plist` file.  (Compiled with py2app.) Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way (Built-in), except for external implementations of Stylesheets, or implementing by yourself..

I highly recommend checking [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48256803/10473393) for one of those.

It speaks about [this stylesheet](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet).

In this thread there are also ways of how to implement it.

Comment: Have I misunderstood this?:
https://www.learnpyqt.com/blog/macos-mojave-dark-mode-support-pyqt5122/

Comment: After some search, i think it is really supported for MacOS Mojave now. But it seems you don't need to implement anything, it will work *out of the box* if you have dark mode enabled. And Mojave's version needs to be 10.14 (or above). Can you somehow confirm this? You can also try running the application without freezing on a MacOS, and checking if it works the intended way.

Comment: I have tried both frozen and directly from source. I shows light mode either way even though my system is set to dark mode.

I have also tried disabling and re-enabling dark mode but that does not change anything. I can't figure out what is wrong...

Comment: `We encourage upgrading to Qt 5.12 to get fixes for macOS 10.14 The maximum supported Xcode version for Qt 5.11 and lower is Xcode 9 (SDK 10.13)` Do you have everything in those versions (Except PyQt, that needs 5.12.2)? Found this here: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/11/08/qt-macos-10-14-mojave/

Comment: I use PyQt 5.13.0.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with this problem myself (PyQt5 5.14) and have figured out how to make macOS' dark mode work with PyQt5. **You have to call `QApplication.setStyle('style name here')`.**

For whatever reason, it seems that any **color scheme changes lay inert until "activated" by `setStyle()`**. (You can see this if you call `QApplication.setPalette(palette)` with a custom palette; some colors will change and others won't—until `setStyle()` is called, upon which all colors finally change.) I can only speculate that dark mode was detected on app start but not activated.

Why it is that color scheme changes don't apply until `setStyle()` is called, I have no idea. I'm guessing it's a bug in PyQt5.

---

There are two rules to make the `setStyle()` trick work:

1. You must call `setStyle()` *after* you've instantiated your `QApplication`. This is in addition to the `setStyle()` call *before* instantiating your `QApplication`, for a total of two `setStyle()`s.
2. `setStyle()` must be called with a string argument. Giving it a `QStyle` object does nothing.

So, to have your app sync color schemes with macOS' dark mode:

```
# Must run before QApplication is instantiated, otherwise certain widget styles will remain unset
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle('fusion')

app = YourQApplicationClassHere(sys.argv)

# Must run after QApplication is instantiated, to apply any latent color scheme changes
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setStyle('fusion')
```

Final caveat: If you freeze your app with pyinstaller, not even the `setStyle()` trick will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this two lines at the very start of your code, before importing PyQt5/PySide2:

```py
import os
os.environ["QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER"] = "1"
```

No need to install a specific qt version, nor set `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` to `false` on `Info.plist`.

Tested on macOS Mojave, Catalina and Big Sur.